# What could be causing my wire terminals to burn off so often?

Tags: inductor, thermal-cutoff

Every 3 to 8 months, my 20-year-old dryer stops producing heat. It started happening about 4 years ago. To repair it, I replace either a thermostat or a thermal fuse. Often, the wire is charred at the terminal end as pictured. I cut back a little past the burned end and crimp on a new female spade terminal. When I repair the unit, I also dismantle and thoroughly vacuum the lint.

[image]

I can't figure out why this problem reoccurs. Over the years, I've made at least 2 or 3 repairs a year. It's now occurring more frequently. **The issue seems to occur during the beginning of the drying cycle. I forgot to mention I once saw a spark across one of the components when I started the dryer with the cover off**.

I've checked all the usual suspects including airflow, lint build-up, etc. My suspicion is now directed at the motor or its circuitry as a possible culprit. The dryer has an induction motor without a start or run capacitor. The motor starts when a push button is pressed. The main and start windings are energized and when the motor reaches full speed, a centrifugal switch disconnected the start winding.

[image: Schematic]

Any pointers on what could be the culprit? As I already mentioned, my dryer is cleaned regularly and gets plenty of air flow. Interestingly, I don't remember ever having to replace the main fuse.

Comment: I wouldn’t take the risk of fire.. 20 yrs was a beautiful period; time for a replacement.

Comment: My guess it is centrifugal switch. It supposed to disconnect the start winding but what happens if it does not act properly. May be too big current and fuse blown after some time.

Comment: Another guess the motors load too high so working current high. Bearings have bad condition.

Comment: First off, what's that wire inside [the yellow circle here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgRL8.png) doing? Is it just laying there? Or is that tied to the chassis? Or is that the wire you are calling attention to as "burned-looking?" I'm not sure from your picture and writing. Also, you do NOT replace ***either*** the thermostat ***or*** the thermal fuse. If the thermal fuse goes, then that tells you that your thermostat isn't working right, as the thermostat allowed the temperature to reach high enough to cause the thermal fuse to go.

Comment: So if the thermal fuse goes, you ***must*** replace the thermostat. That behavior alone may account for ***some*** of what you consider to be your problem. There may be more than this. But if you are replacing ***only*** the thermal fuse and allowing a bad thermostat to continue, then you are just asking for trouble, again. So fix that behavior -- as a starting point. If your wires are showing burned ends, then this suggests to me that the copper in the wires are degraded and should be replaced, along with those connector ends. Then polish the metal tabs they connect onto, as well!

Comment: Finally, you say that you clean out all the lint. What I'm also now wondering about is what's inside the heater box itself. Have you opened that up enough to see what it looks like inside it? Dryers are ***NOT*** rocket science (well, except the new ones with fancy computers in them which turn them into pinball machines.) They have only a very few and simple ideas that have been used and reused by every manufacturer since I don't know when -- before I was born, maybe even. You should be able to apply yourself to the data you have as evidence and what can and cannot be the cause.

Comment: @RemyHx Yes, I could buy another appliance like my new Frigidaire refrigerator which has far more problems than my last one. If I only had to fix it as often as I do my dryer, I would be far happier.

Comment: @user263983. Hmmm. You're on to something.  I don't hear any odd noises from the motor, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have any issues. It could be the centrifugal switch. My other thought is that there may be a snubber somewhere that's blown out. If that happens, you'd never know and excessive current would be a feature.

Comment: @jonk.  The yellow circle is the wire that burned off at the terminals. This is one of the worst cases. I can't remember how many times I've actually replaced all the thermal fuses and thermostats together. The wire ends have been stripped and crimped numerous times at every segment of the circuit. There's really no consistency to the location of the failure.

Comment: @user148298 Got it about that wire, then. It doesn't heat up like that unless there is sufficient resistance exactly at that point to heat it up a lot. So you ***know*** for sure that you have a problem at the connector that you have not solved. I'll also take it from you that I don't see all the data you have. You've only presented a tiny part of it. So I'll leave it to you to process all the info you have that I don't. Still, this isn't a difficult system and it's just a matter of observation and the application of valid logic and physical theory to yield sound results. Best wishes!

Comment: @user148298 The connector issue could be the copper in the wire. But you say you've replaced the wires. Could be the connector. But you say you replaced the connectors. Finally, could be the tab these things are attached to -- oxidation? In any case, none of this changes the simple fact that it's heating up a lot right at the connector. You've proven that result. There's nothing else that can artificially *direct* heat from elsewhere right at the connector itself. That's obvious here. So either you are doing something wrong or you've got some chemical action taking place at a very high rate.

Comment: @user148298 If it is chemical, the question may be: Do you live near a salt water environment or close to an area that frequently salts its streets for ice and snow?

Comment: i edited my question and highlighted details in bold.

Answer (score 3):

Are you crimping those replacement terminals sufficiently?

If you are doing what many do and just using pointed pliers or even sidecutters then then the crimp will be loose - in electrical current terms even if you cannot pull it off easily.

Also, what is the quality of the crimp terminals? the cheap ones are soft while the originals tend to be copper or a copper alloy and need a decent crimping plier.

Comment: I don't mess around with bad crimpers and terminals because it always leads to revisiting the repair later.

Answer (score 2):

Severe/Excess heat on the crimp-connection is a good indicator of high current flow.
If there is a multimeter at hand measure the AC-current during normal operation flowing out of the motor -> Compare it with the datasheet.

If it is far out of limits replace the motor - i dont know the cost, but safety first!
If it is at the edge of boundaries give it a good service. Replace bearings/Seal/brushes etc. and inspect windings carefully. Also check insulation for visual defects and perform the common electrical test (Resistance, insulation voltage, etc.)

You can also check the winding resistance as a good starter. Any multimeter will do.

Also check insulation resistance between connections and chassis etc. Maybe the insulation gets old and a huge residual current flows. There are dedicated testing devices for this purpose out there. A good multimeter will do.

Comment: I am now thinking about the centrifugal switch. If the windings are sufficiently energized, they can dump a ton of current into the circuit. I wonder if there's a snubber that may have gone bad, but I don't see it in the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

### A thermal fuse is *not a consumable*

*Or, stop buying new canaries, and get out of the coal mine!*

A thermal fuses is a protective device. Like any protective device, it protects *something else* and is designed to **fail first** to prevent a more destructive failure of some other thing.

You are not recognizing that important function, and are consider it to be a "nuisance trip" merely because it actually is a nuisance to you.  That is entirely wrong-headed.

### The thermal trip reveals a failure of the heating element

Either it is failing internally, or possibly being so clogged with material that it cannot cool properly which is elevating its temperature.  Regardless, the heating element should be serviced.  (which means "replaced" unless you find a fixable problem in there).

In the future when protective devices fail, assume the protective device *is not* defective and did its job properly.  Then investigate what it is protecting from, and repair *that*.

That doubly applies when you have already replaced the protective device once.
It *quadruply* applies if GFCI / RCD is involved in any way.

### The lint should be departing the building out the vent.

From time to time we get knuckleheads who decide to run a dryer *without a dryer vent*.  This fills the laundry room with exhaust air that is hot, humid **and full of lint**. The dryer is not designed to ingest air thick with lint.

If you want to run a dryer without a dryer vent, get a **heat pump dryer**. This will save a fortune in electricity, and save you more in air conditioning and dehumidification costs (or mold and mildew cleanup costs if you don't deal with the humidity).  The heat pump dryer is fully self-contained and ejects nothing but water.  And lint.

Note that the heat pump dryer also cures a critical flaw in vented dryers where a vent *is* used: those eject perfectly conditioned air outside, drawing a vacuum on the building *which then sucks outside air through every crack and leak in the building*.  This outside air is the wrong temperature *and humidity*, and the HVAC must work harder to condition it.

Not to be confused with heat pump water heaters, which steal the heat in the utility room and put it in the water. The heat pump dryer's effects cancel each other out, radiating only the heat corresponding to the wattage of the machine.

Comment: Your presumption is that the thermal fuse and thermostats failed due to excessive temperature. This isn't the case since they fail randomly with a burnt wire end. I should have mentioned the failure happens early in the drying process.

Comment: @user148298 so you are claiming the heating element is NOT getting hotter than it's supposed to?  LOL clearly something thermal is going on there that shouldn't. You think the thermal fuse is making that heat all by itself?

Comment: Yes, there's something thermal going on, but that thermal isn't what is causing the fuse to fail. First, the burnt wires are more consistent with overcurrent than the heat from the dyer. Second, the burnt wires invariably happen well before the heater starts.  This leads me to suspect it's caused by a large inrush current produced by the motor upon hitting the start switch.

Comment: @user148298 You're the expert.  But does motor current even go through that wire?

Comment: Yes. Look at the diagram. It's in series with the motor.